# How to use Python 3.5 style async and await in Tornado for websockets?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

Consider this short snippet:

```
import tornado
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.gen
import tornado.web

class NewWsHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.write_message("echo " + message)

class OldWsHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def on_message(self, message):
        yield self.write_message("echo " + message)

app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', OldWsHandler)])
app.listen(8080)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

`OldWsHandler` uses the pre-3.5 way of doing asynchronous functions in Tornado, and it works fine. However, [as the documentation states](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#python-3-5-async-and-await), it is preferred to use [PEP 0492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) for readability and speed.

The documentation says:

> Simply use `async def foo()` in place of a function definition with the `@gen.coroutine` decorator, and `await` in place of `yield`.

So I wrote `NewWsHandler`. However, when sending a websocket message, it raises a warning:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py:417: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_message' was never awaited
  callback(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't really know how to (properly) fix it. I tried decorating it in `tornado.web.asynchronous`, but that assumes a [HTTP verb method](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous). So after I override `finish()` (websockets are not allowed to do that), it seems to be kind of working:

```
class NewWsHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def finish(self):
        pass

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.write_message("echo " + message)
```

But this still looks hackerish, and seems to be contradicting the documentation. What is the right way of doing this?

Note: I am using Python 3.5.1 and Tornado 4.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coroutines are called differently than regular functions; therefore when subclassing and overriding methods you cannot change a regular method in the base class into a coroutine in your subclass (unless the base class specifically says this is OK). `WebSocketHandler.on_message` may not be a coroutine (as of Tornado 4.3; this may change in the future).

Instead, if you need to do something asynchronous in response to a message, put the asynchronous parts in a separate function and call it with `IOLoop.current().spawn_callback`. (or if `write_message` is the only async thing you're doing, just call it synchronously)

---

## Update

This changed in Tornado 4.5, `WebSocketHandler.on_message` can now be used as a coroutine. See http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v4.5.0.html#tornado-websocket.

Comment: Is there some way I could query a database (asynchronously) in response to a websocket message then? Something like `result = await query(...)`? I can't seem to find an actual good way of doing this. (Aside from the 'hacks' in my question).

Comment: Once you've spawned a separate callback you can do whatever you want. You'll just need to be careful with exception handling since any exception raised here won't pass through `on_message` and affect the websocket connection. Also be aware that another message may come in before the previous one has finished; to avoid that you may want to spawn a callback in `on_open()` and communicate with it using a Queue.