# Tornado asyncio tcp server throws AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop'

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, tornado, python-asyncio

I am trying to build a tcp server using Tornado and Asyncio. In the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html?highlight=await#python-3-5-async-and-await) of Tornado they say that `await` and `async` should work as a replacement for `tornado.gen.coroutine` decorator, but I have a problem starting this server. What I am doing wrong here?

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer
from tornado.iostream import StreamClosedError
from tornado.platform.asyncio import to_asyncio_future

class Server(TCPServer):

    async def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        """Called when new IOStream object is ready for usage"""
        print('Incoming connection from %r', address)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await to_asyncio_future(stream.read_until('\n'.encode('utf8')))
                print("Message: ", message)
            except StreamClosedError:
                print("Good bye!!")
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    IOLoop.configure('tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop')
    server = Server(io_loop=IOLoop.current().asyncio_loop)
    server.listen(7000)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tornadoasyncioserver.py", line 41, in <module>
    server.listen(7000)
  File "/Users/user/tornadotcp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 127, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "/Users/user/tornadotcp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 144, in add_sockets
    io_loop=self.io_loop)
  File "/Users/user/tornadotcp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 275, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute 'add_handler'
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `Server(io_loop=IOLoop.current().asyncio_loop)` to `Server(io_loop=IOLoop.current())` since Server awaits IOLoop, not the asyncio loop itself.

Comment: Now I have this error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/tornadotcp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 271, in _handle_connection
    self.io_loop.add_future(future, lambda f: f.result())
  File "/Users/user/tornadotcp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 589, in add_future
    assert is_future(future)
AssertionError
/Users/user/tornadotcp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py:274: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Server.handle_stream' was never awaited
  callback(connection, address)`

Comment: That seems to be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542864/how-to-use-python-3-5-style-async-and-await-in-tornado